# JUnit Testing with Spring MVC : Initialization error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

This is my first try with JUnit testing and Spring MVC.
I have made a test configuration class for beans and one test class for controller. While executing the test, there is test failure which says `Initialization error and no class definition found error`.
Following is my `TestBeanConfig.java` file

```
package com.mkyong.controller;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mkyong.controller")
public class TestBeanConfig {

    @Bean
    MultiplicationService multiplicationservice() {
    return new MultiplicationService();
    }

    @Bean
    NumberDAO numberDao() {
    NumberDAO numberdao =new NumberDAO();
    return numberdao;
    }
}
```

and MultiplicationServiceTest.java

```
package com.mkyong.controller;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes={TestBeanConfig.class})
public class MultiplicationServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MultiplicationService multiplytestobject;

    MockMvc mockMvc ;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    public MultiplicationServiceTest() {

    }

    public MultiplicationService getMultiplytestobject() {
        return multiplytestobject;
    }

    public void setMultiplytestobject(MultiplicationService multiplytestobject) {
        this.multiplytestobject = multiplytestobject;
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testHandleMultiply() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(post("/multiply").param("number1","7").param("number2","7"))
    .andExpect((model().attribute("result", "49")))
    .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/multiply.jsp"));
    }

}
```

Trace of error:

```
Tests in error: 
  initializationError(com.mkyong.controller.MultiplicationServiceTest): Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.test.context.web.WebDelegatingSmartContextLoader]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.626s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Jan 28 15:40:26 IST 2018
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/180M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.9:test (default-test) on project bmfinal: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to maven pom.xml dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This should provide classes project's searching for.

Let me know if it helps you out.

Comment: It has solved the initialization error. However other error has appeared.              Tests in error: 
  testHandleMultiply(com.mkyong.controller.MultiplicationServiceTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext

Comment: this leads to tal different scenario. Did u used applicationContext.xml ?You've started from Mkyong tutorial isn'it? which one?

Comment: i did not use applicationContext.xml. i started spring mvc with mkyong counter webapp project. for testing i had referred some other sources.

Comment: are you using Eclipse or STS?

Comment: eclipse. After writing TestBeanConfig.java do i need to use applicationContext.xml for configuration?

Comment: it's not necessary if I remember well. let me reproduce your scenario.

Comment: Please try editing like this:
@ContextConfiguration(classes=TestBeanConfig.class, loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)

Comment: Do I need to add some dependency for loader? Eclipse shows error for AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class cannot be resolved to type.

Comment: Sure: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: Again initialization error.  initializationError(com.mkyong.controller.MultiplicationServiceTest)

Comment: post the full stack please

Comment: There was no much stack produced. It just shows:  Tests in error: 
  initializationError(com.mkyong.controller.MultiplicationServiceTest)

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

Comment: Which JUnit version you have? Probably 4.11. Please try updating to 4.12 an rerun test.

Comment: I have uploaded my project on github link: https://github.com/Disha1308/bmfinal/                                                                                                      After changing the version I have faced new bootstrap error:Tests in error: 
  initializationError(com.mkyong.controller.MultiplicationServiceTest): Could not load TestContextBootstrapper [null]. Specify @BootstrapWith's 'value' attribute or make the default bootstrapper class available.

Comment: Oh, it's a mismatch inside spring dependencies. Amend like this:<dependency> 
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
<artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
 <version>${spring.version}</version>
 </dependency>

Comment: It did not help either. failed to load application context.

Comment: @DishaAgrawal :), you must put `*.xml` into `src/test/resources` directory.

Comment: yes that solved my problem. I added application-context.xml in src/main/resources folder and with @ContextConfiguration I used location parameter like this @ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:app-context.xml") and all test were successful. Thank you Black.Jack and holi-java

Comment: I took your project and made it run without xml resources. Tell me if it's needed.

Comment: Yes sure. i would like to see.